# Saltstack: Error: unable to cache file 'salt://foo/bar/test.sh' from saltenv base in minion

Tags: salt-stack

I have configured 2 env in salt prod & nonprod. In nonprod env I am trying the schedule a job which will run a script in the minion.

These are my files looks like... Salt version is 3001.1

## /etc/salt/master

```yaml
file_roots:
  nonprod:
    - /srv/salt/nonprod
  prod:
    - /srv/salt/prod

pillar_roots:
  nonprod:
    - /srv/nonprod_pillar
  prod:
    - /srv/prod_pillar
```

## /srv/salt/nonprod/top.sls

```yaml
nonprod:
  minion1:
    - match: glob
    - foo.bar
```

## /srv/salt/nonprod/foo/bar/init.sls

```yaml
backup_job:
  schedule.present:
    - function: cmd.script
    - job_args:
      - salt://foo/bar/test.sh
      - env: nonprod
    - when:
      - Monday 02:36am
```

The script "test.sh" is present under `/srv/salt/nonprod/foo/bar/test.sh`

Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the Minion is looking for the `test.sh` in "base" environment. It is possible that the `job_args` you passed with the environment name was ignored.

There is another way to reference files from Salt master - by appending `?saltenv=<envname>` to the file source.

Something like below:

```yaml
backup-job:
  schedule.present:
    - function: cmd.script
    - job_args:
        - salt://foo/bar/test.sh?saltenv=nonprod
    - when:
        - Monday 10:30pm
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in my question...I have already tried that. I have also tried putting as below. But the result is same.

- job_args:
        - salt://foo/bar/test.sh
        - saltenv=nonprod

Comment: Seems you have multiple top files. What's the setting for `top_file_merging_strategy`? Or does it work with single top file  having `nonprod` environment in `/srv/salt/top.sls`?

Comment: I have only 1 top file /srv/salt/top.sls with 2 environments in it... 1) nonprod 2) prod

Comment: Your question states otherwise, you have posted contents of: `/srv/salt/nonprod/top.sls` . I've the different environments in `/srv/salt/top.sls`, and job runs fine when added as given in the answer.

Comment: oh sorry about the confusion. The top file is /srv/salt/top.sls but because of 2 environments it works like /srv/salt/nonprod/top.sls and /srv/salt/prod/top.sls. That's why I mentioned like that.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by adding "environment: nonprod" in the minion conf file. Looks like the minion was trying to find the file in the base(default) environment. Thanks for your help.